# Formatting web content.

Tags: html, css

I developed a small website with 15-20 pages.

The site consists of -

1. Header menu.
2. Content (this is different for each page).
3. Footer.

I somehow not able to digest the fact that I have to write the code for header menu and footer on all the pages.

Can someone please help me understand how can i manage to write repetitive code in one place and import it or include it in all the pages.

Also, it'll be a bonus if you can mention how can one handle the same case with the javascript code, images and css too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very broad and generic AND very much on the right track. It seems as though you are approaching this site building project from a very static perspective while you actually need to approach it dynamically.

The bare minimum that you can do is to use SSI as suggested here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes

Now, depending on your level of knowledge and willingness to learn you will be able to accomplish this much more elegantly if you use a scripting language such as php for example.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/

Scripting languages allow you to create content once and then include the file with that content with a single line of code into another file. PLUS do a lot more with it down the road if your website needs to grow.

For example, you can create header.php and footer.php and include them in your pages that must also be php files. That way you only create header and footer once and re-use them..

If you create header.php and put your header code into that file ... And then you create somepage.php which is your content page.. In order to include the header code you have to write this into some page.php where you want your header to be

```
<?Php include('header.php'); ?>
```

It is important that you respect the html containing elements structure. The SSI method literally injects exact content as is in included file.

You can literally split one file in multiple parts, save them as php and include them into third file and get the same result as the original file was.

You do have to insure that your hosting server supports dynamic scripting language that you want to use. Most hosts support PHP.

Also, as far as including JavaScript goes. If you write JavaScript properly then you can write all your JavaScript code in .js files and then include those files into your php or html files when needed. The same goes for CSS files. You put CSS code into style.css file and link the file to your something.php

This is how you include JavaScript files.. 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp
You usually put this into  element of your page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsfile.js"></script>
```

This is how you link a css file with your other files.. 
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp
You put this into  element of your page.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```

However,,,

All this is still pretty rudimentary. Maybe you should look into using hosted WordPress or a similar content management system to help you build a nice dynamic web site.

Or, a good way to start, if you have a desire to actually learn, is to learn basics from www.w3schools.com

You will need to go through

HTML and HTML5, 
CSS2 and CSS3, 
PHP (this is what allows for dynamic stuff- you can try learning python alternatively.. I prefer php myself), 
JavaScript, 
JSON

And then when you learn JavaScript you will want to get into JavaScript libraries,, like jQuery and ultimately Angularjs (this is a more advanced library but very useful)

Also you will want to learn how to use databases to store data so you don't have to create a new page at all every time. You should look into using MySQL with PHP for that. You could alternatively look into Postgress, liteSQL and other options too.

All of these, except for Angularjs are available to learn for free at w3schools website. You can just google it.

One more thing...

This may seem intimidating but if you suspend that feeling at first and stick through the very first paradigm challenges you will learn that it is not at all that complicated.

Good luck!

P.S.

My web programming career started 15 years ago when I tried building a small site and got frustrated with exactly the same problem you are facing now :)

Comment: I appreciate your deep insightful answer. Cant ask for anything more. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome :) and you may want to look at this http://www.w3schools.com/sitemap/default.asp

Answer (score 1):

You may use Server Side Includes (SSI) if your server supports it (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes).

As for css and javascript - move code and declaration to separate files and include link to them on your pages (usually in head element) like this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript-file.js"></script>` and 
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css-file.css" />` (see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp for details).